# Which function is called when changing a directory in FUSE?

Tags: c, filesystems, libraries, fuse

I'm making a filesystem using FUSE, and know I have a doubt. When I use the "cd" command in the new filesystem, it changes to directories that doesn't exist.

For example, if the directory "m" doesn't exist, and I make a "cd m" it changes to that directory.

Which is the function that FUSE calls when the directory is changed? Why is the app doing the problem I describe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you implementing getattr? and if so, are you making sure to return -ENOENT if the path they give you doesn't correspond to a file or directory in your system?

Comment: Yes, I'm implementing getattr and I return the -ENOENT, but I was doing something wrong... I'm going to put the code in another answer.

Comment: I can't put the code because I'm new user... But, I hope that you can help me with this...
When I change the current directory with "cd" command... which function is called? It will be very helpfull to me to use a variable to control the level of the directories...

Comment: Sorry, don't know what to tell you in that case. I was under the impression FUSE just called getattr to see if the name the user typed in corresponded to a directory. I'm not aware of any other functions it would try if getattr tells it that the directory entry does not exist, and I seem to have broken my FUSE install so I can't even compile a simple program to test it.